# Adding hreflang to head section. How to get translated url

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.2

I'm trying to update my NopCommerce 4.20 webshop and implement SEO suggestions.
One suggestion is to add `hreflang` links to the header of each page, pointing to the different translated pages.

I implemented the following code in `_Root.Head.cshtml`:

```cs
    // Languages for hreflang tags:
    var allLanguages = languageService.GetAllLanguages();
    var segments = webHelper.GetThisPageUrl(false).Split('/');
    var pageUrl = "";
    for (var i = 4; i < segments.Length; i++)
    {
        pageUrl = $"{pageUrl}/{segments[i]}";
    }

    <!-- Show languages -->
    @foreach (var language in allLanguages)
    {
        var hreflang = languageService.GetTwoLetterIsoLanguageName(language).ToLower();
        var url = $"{webHelper.GetStoreLocation()}{hreflang}/{pageUrl}";
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="@hreflang" href="@url" />
    }
```

This results in:

```html
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.josephiena.nl/en/foto-draak-in-de-lucht-digif-006">
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="https://www.josephiena.nl/nl/foto-draak-in-de-lucht-digif-006">
```

Although the EN link is working, the actual URL should be `https://www.josephiena.nl/en/photo-dragon-in-the-sky-digif-006`, because I also translated the title and thus the 'Search engine friendly page name' is also translated.

How do I get the correct translated URL?